# How do I integrate an ASM obj file with a C++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, masm, masm32

I want to integrate ASM and C++ code in Visual Studio 2010. Basically, I want to be able to use certain routines created in ASM in my C++ code.

So I want to know:

1. How do I add the ASM obj files to VS2010 in the first place?
2. How do I call a function in the ASM code from the C++ part of the code?
3. Suppose that I make a function (in ASM) that computes a value and stores the value in the tax register. Let's say its called compute. Will I be able to receive the return value in C++ using something like: `int val=compute();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these samples have what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t13a3526%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

You will have to let visual studio automatically "convert" them to the new project format, but I just tried it with the PRIMESSTEP2 example and it worked.

All you need is a function prototype like:

```
void sieve(void);  // prototype for Sieve of Eratosthenes function
```

And then you can implement them in asm and they will link together. You return values by placing them in the EAX register and it will come through as a return value in C / C++.

Comment: The examples use C, instead of C++. So they do not work in C++. Even when i just changed the format of the file from .c to.cpp, I received a linker error(unresolved external referenced in main)

Comment: You probably need to make the prototype extern "C".

Comment: I did that. It worked. But then i tried one of my files and it didn't work. Then i realized that the calling convention needs to be c, rather than stdcall. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use inline assembler?

Comment: I don't know about that, but I want to do it this way if it is possible. Also, note that I use some of MASM32's macros and stuff, and I don't know whether that would be possible using inline assembler. Even if it would be, I'd like to know how to do it this way, since I want to keep my options open and, well, I'm very curious about it.

Comment: Well, you would probably have to rewrite your asm code anyway to make it fit into VS C++ compiler convention, basically you have to put return value into right register.

Comment: The return values are stored in eax, as far as I know. I may be wrong though. However, would it be possible to make an obj file using the MASM, and then linking it to the C++ obj file created by Visual Studio?

Comment: I guess Project proporties -> Configuration proporties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies should work.